# Automatic ScrollView

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is there a solution for making an automatically scrolling view? I have multiple images. For example: first image is 320 x 10000 , second is 320 8000.

I have this code.

This is the DataManager:

```
<code>
#import "DataManager.h"

@interface DataManager ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray * myArr;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray * myArrTitoli;

@end

@implementation DataManager

static DataManager *sharedClassInstance = nil;

+ (DataManager *)sharedClass {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (!sharedClassInstance)
            sharedClassInstance = [[DataManager alloc] init];
        return sharedClassInstance;
    }
}

- (void)setupDM {
    UIImage * img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Storia1.png"];
    UIImage * img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Storia1.png"];

self.myArr = @[img1, img2];


    UIImage * button1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"storia_1_button.png"];
    UIImage * button2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"storia_2_button.png"];
    UIImage * button3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"storia_3_button.png"];

    self.myArrTitoli = @[button1, button2, button3];

}

- (int)productsCount {
    return self.myArrTitoli.count;
}

- (UIImage*)imageForRow:(int)row {
    return self.myArr[row];
}

- (UIImage*)buttonForRow:(int)row {
    return self.myArrTitoli[row];
}

@end

</code>
```

I have a Table View with bottom that select. This is a UiViewController of Story.

```
#import "StoryViewController.h"

@interface StoryViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *storyImage;

@end

@implementation StoryViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.storyImage.image = self.ponteImage;

    [scroller setScrollsToTop:NO];
    [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 10000)];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

But this method doesn't work.

Can you help me? I want a automatically scrolling view , if there is a image with 10000 px or 8000 or 6000.

Thank you.

Comment: Try improve your question little bit, because I have no idea what this __I want a scroll view automatic__ does really mean.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have connect your IBOutlet
2. To scroll to define position use:

   [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(positionX, 0)];

Comment: I'm sorry for my question. Now i have 3 image: first image is 320x8000 the second 320x6000. third 320 x 8000. Now the scroll view works. But I have to set the height of the scroll. I want my scrollview is automatic. There is the possibility of putting width 320 height automatic?

Comment: or do I have to put three images three different scroll view?

Comment: I solved it. Necessary to give priority 1 in the contraints as regards the constant of image. so now sets the height of the ScrollView automatically.